# why java files in android studio Different from the java file Extract from classes.dex

Tags: java, android, android-studio, apk

I have an application on the android studio
and I have apk when I extracted the Java files from the apk
They were not the same code on the android studio why ?

Answer (score 0):

Your compiled java files usually goes through a process called obfuscation by using an app called [proguard](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/products/proguard).

Here's what [obfuscation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation) explained by wiki:

> Obfuscation is the obscuring of the intended meaning of communication by making the message difficult to understand, usually with confusing and ambiguous language. The obfuscation might be either unintentional or intentional (although intent usually is connoted), and is accomplished with circumlocution (talking around the subject), the use of jargon (technical language of a profession), and the use of an argot (ingroup language) of limited communicative value to outsiders.

Since it is already obfuscated, when you reverse the bytecode back to a java file, it will be different than the actual file. However, coding structure and such will remain the same.